# How to change the dimensions of a div depending of a number extern to that div? jquery/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the dimensions of a `div` depending of wich number contain another `div`. For example if i have the number 0 the div has to be `width: 20px; height 0px;`, if i have the number 50 the div has to be `width: 20px; height 50px;`, if i have the number 100 the `div` has to be `width: 20px; height 100px;`.

How can I do it in css or jquery?

I hope you understand. Thank you.

Comment: Can include `html`, `css`, `js` , tried at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `css()` function :

```js
$('#div-2').css("height", $('#div-1').text()+'px');
```

```css
#div-2{
   background-color: green;
   width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div-1'>50</div>
<div id='div-2'></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This definitely is more extensive but why all the additional code if he just wants to change one simple property.

Comment: How can I do if i have a counter and not a second div?

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi what you means exactly by counter?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to which on passing the width it will change your width to what you passed.

```
function ChangeHeight(val){
   $('#div').css('height', val+'px');
}
ChangeHeight(100);
```

or simply do this if its just gonna be once per page lifetime.

```
$('#div').css('height', val+'px');
```

This should do for you.

Comment: How can I do if I have a dinamic number like a counter and not a number always egual like your 'val'?

Comment: Well simply call the function or the change the property everytime your number changes.. I showed you the way you can do it.. but how and where you need to implement depends on your actual requirements.